# Why can Standard User create a child object for a Parent record that is locked by an Approval Process?

Tags: custom-object, approval-process

The setup is that we have a Custom Object that is Parent to 16 different Child object types.  When we "Submit for Approval" the process automatically locks the record (by default, per standard Salesforce approval process initial submission).  14 of the 16 child object types are locked as well and cannot have their records edited or have a new record created, but for some reason 2 of the objects are not blocked from record creation by the locking of the parent object.

This is strange for the lowest Users who do not have Modify All privileges on any of the child objects (which, according to the documentation, would allow them to circumvent the Record Lock).  I've run several tests and examined security settings and object settings to find a difference between these two objects and the others, but I do not see anything that would allow this to happen.  Any ideas why this would be possible?

Comment: Just to clarify a bit, the children are all of the same SObjectType right? Are they in a master-detail or lookup relationship with the parent.

Comment: They are all master-detail relationships.

Comment: And the answer to the first question?

Comment: They are all Custom objects, if that is what you are asking.  Otherwise, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I'm trying to understand if you have 16 child object instances all of the same type (e.g. "MyCustomObject__c") or that you have 16 different types of child object (e.g. "MyCustomObject1_c", "MyCustomObject2__c" etc).

Comment: Ah, they are 16 custom types.  Each with a master-detail relationship to the same parent type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways a user can circumvent the Record Lock put in place by an approval process:

1. Users who have the "Modify All" access for a particular object are able to edit a record that is locked, regardless of whether they are an approver or not.
2. Under the Master-Detail Options section of a Master-Detail data type
   field, there is a setting called "Sharing Setting".  If the setting
   is set to "Read Only" then Users only require Read Access to
   create/edit/delete related detail records.  This also seems to
   circumvent the Record Lock for record Creation (although,
   edit/deleting still seem to be disabled).